# WordPress site loads Correctly, when login as admin

Tags: wordpress, caching

WordPress site loads Correctly, when login as admin.
Normal users didn't get the website in correct style
the  Url of my site

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be cache issue, clear you cache. Usually WordPress cache plugins don't store cache for Admin user.